# Django annotate not giving values for a many to many field

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I wrote a views function:

```
def get_lists(request,user_email):
    """Get all the lists made by user"""
    try:
        user_instance = MyUser.objects.get(email=user_email)
    except MyUser.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'message':'User not found'}),status=404)

    if request.method == 'GET':


        influencers_list = UserInfluencerGroupList.objects.filter(user=user_instance).annotate(total_reach=Sum('influencers__followers'),total_engagement=Sum('influencers__avg_picture_engagement')).order_by('id')

        influencers_list = serializers.serialize('json',influencers_list, fields =['id','influencers','list_name','total_reach'], indent=2, use_natural_foreign_keys=True, use_natural_primary_keys=True)


        return HttpResponse(influencers_list,content_type='application/json',status=200)
    else:
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'message':'No lists found'}), status=400)
```

I want to return the total number of followers of all the influencers in each list and also their total_engagement. However after using the annotate field, the json object returned doesn't have the total number of followers or the total_engagement in each list.

How should I use annotate to display the total number of followers of all the influencers in each list and also their total_engagement.

My django model is as follows:

```
class UserInfluencerGroupList(models.Model):
    list_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    influencers = models.ManyToManyField(Influencer, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Your problem is not with annotation, but with serialization. The built-in serializers are not very customizable; if you want to customise serialization at all you should use something like Django REST Framework's ModelSerializer classes.

Comment: How can I customize the serializers to display the annotation values?

Comment: I just said: you can't. You need to use something else, like DRF's ModelSerializers.